# Using R to parse DOM in HTML

Tags: r, dom

I'm trying to scrap a table from a HTML file and using R to parse it.
For example,if the body element in the HTML file has the following tags and I want to navigate the DOM tree to get the `second <div>` in something like this: `body <- pagetree$children$html$children$body`, how to do it? probably it's something like  `content = body$children`...?
How to specifically refer to that div? Is it by using the attributes or the sequence of the child node with respect to it's parents?

```
 names(body)
   script    script      link      link 
 "script"  "script"    "link"    "link" 
     link      link      link   comment 
   "link"    "link"    "link" "comment" 
  comment       div    script       div 
"comment"     "div"  "script"     "div" 
      div    script       div    script 
    "div"  "script"     "div"  "script" 
   script    script 
 "script"  "script"
```

Answer (score 0):

Not clear from your question if you know this - but you should probably use the package `XML`.

Answer (score 0):

The [rvest](https://github.com/hadley/rvest) package is one I have used to scrape and navigate html. It has commands that parse and allow you to navigate through tags pretty easily. The [xml2](https://github.com/hadley/xml2) package can work if you need to navigate xml files too.